# iOS : How to attach a multiple attachment file in one button using pickerview method?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, uipickerview

I have a multiple file to attach inside the picker view. When user select that picker view item, they can click email button to attach the chosen file. How do I do so in my picker view?

Here is my sample code.

M File :

```
-(void)pickerViewEmail:(UIPickerView *)pickerViewEmail didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{


    if ([[musicList objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"m1"])
    {

        MFMailComposeViewController *pickerEmail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        pickerEmail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"m1" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [pickerEmail addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"audio/mp3" fileName:@"m1"];

        [pickerEmail setSubject:@"Hello!"];

        // Set up recipients
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
        NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
        NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

        [pickerEmail setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        [pickerEmail setCcRecipients:ccRecipients]; 
        [pickerEmail setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

        // Fill out the email body text
        NSString *emailBody = @"Hello";
        [pickerEmail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:pickerEmail animated:YES];
        [pickerEmail release];

    }
```

Email Button: How do i start from here.

```
-(IBAction)showEmail
{

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
                 [self pickerEmail]; I have a yellow error when i call this. What is the right solution?

    }

    else
    {

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

When user selects rows in your pickerviews, you save row titles to some common variables
using

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

You can use one pickerView delegate method for all your pickerViews. To determine, which pickerView is selected you should retrieve sender.

Then in your showEmail method you just use that saved variables.

Sample code. Just bind 3 different delegates to 3 sliders in IB:

```
-(IBAction)slider1Changed:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *) sender;
    int progressAsInt =(int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
    NSString *newText =[[NSString alloc]
                        initWithFormat:@"%d",progressAsInt];
    label1.text = newText;
    NSString *imgFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"gold%i.png", progressAsInt];
    image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imgFileName];

    [newText release];
}

-(IBAction)slider2Changed:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *) sender;
    int progressAsInt =(int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
    NSString *newText =[[NSString alloc]
                        initWithFormat:@"%d",progressAsInt];
    label2.text = newText;
    NSString *imgFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"gold%i.png", progressAsInt];
    image2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imgFileName];
    [newText release];
}

-(IBAction)slider3Changed:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *) sender;
    int progressAsInt =(int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
    NSString *newText =[[NSString alloc]
                        initWithFormat:@"%d",progressAsInt];
    label3.text = newText;
    NSString *imgFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"gold%i.png", progressAsInt];
    image3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imgFileName];
    [newText release];
}
```

Comment: I did some code amendment up there. I probably need a sample on how to retrieve sender. And I'm truely beginner. I have a variable called emailMe in the code amendment.

Comment: You mean I need two pickerView delegate method :one for playing and one for email?

Comment: When user changes values of your picker views, the value of your class variable changes. Then when user presses button, showEmail is called and you use a value of your class variable. I updated my answer - added some example code for you. This is a code for case of 3 sliders on one view. Each slider has it's own delegate.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will experimenting it.