# iOS : How to retrieve sender in one IBAction from the multiple item in picker view selection?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, messageui

I need one button called email button to do one selection from multiple item from picker view to attach that selected item via email. I am stuck at the IBAction. Here is my progress.

M File :

```
    -(void)pickerViewEmail:(UIPickerView *)pickerViewEmail didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

    {

        if ([[musicList objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"m1"])
        {

            MFMailComposeViewController *pickerEmail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            pickerEmail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

            NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"m1" ofType:@"mp3"];
            NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
            [pickerEmail addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"audio/mp3" fileName:@"m1"];

            [pickerEmail setSubject:@"Hello!"];

            // Set up recipients
            NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
            NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
            NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

            [pickerEmail setToRecipients:toRecipients];
            [pickerEmail setCcRecipients:ccRecipients]; 
            [pickerEmail setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

            // Fill out the email body text
            NSString *emailBody = @"Hello";
            [pickerEmail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

            [self presentModalViewController:pickerEmail animated:YES];
            [pickerEmail release];

        }


 if ([[musicList objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"m2"])
        {

        }
 if ([[musicList objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"m3"])
        {

        }
```

IBAction :

```
-(IBAction)showEmail
{

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
                 [self pickerEmail]; I have a yellow error when i call this. What is the right solution?

    }

    else
    {

    }


}
```

[iOS : How to attach a multiple attachment file in one button using pickerview method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8755403/1082085)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your call `[self pickerEmail]`
Higher in your code, `pickerEmail` seems to be an object, of type `MFMailComposeViewController`, not a method. So the call `[self pickerEmail]` does not have any sense in Objective-C

Comment: My knowledge is limited until here that's why if someone can suggest the right sence because im learning by practical of understanding of OOP.